# Showing contact/About page generated from admin page in django 1.9

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I am a newbie to Django. I am creating a blog page with django 1.9. I am trying to create an About page which can be updated with image and some content from the admin page. When I go to the about page, It does not display anything. It appears the model does not return anything. I am not sure where I am wrong.

Here are the code of my pages.

models.py

```
class About(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    about_body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=False)

    objects = AboutAuthor.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("about_author", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

class AboutAuthor(models.QuerySet):
  def published(self):
    print("ABOUTAUTHOR: {}".format(self.all()))
    return self.all()
```

views.py

```
class About(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.About.objects.published()
    print("inside About view queryset={}".format(queryset))
    model = models.About
    template_name = "About.html"
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.VBlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.VBlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
url(r'^about/$', views.About.as_view(), name='about_author'),
url(r'^feed/$', feed.LatestPosts(), name="feed"),
]
```

home_page.html

```
<li><a href="{{ about_author.get_absolute_url }}/about">About</a></li>
```

About.html

```
{% load django_markdown %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}

{% block blog_entries %}

<div class='post-outer'>
  <article class='post hentry'>
    <header class='entry-header'>
      <h1 class='post-title entry-title'>
        About the Author
      </h1>
    </header>
    <div class='post-header-line-1'></div>
  <div class='post-body entry-content'>
  <div>
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
      <img src="{{objects.image}}" class="pbtthumbimg"/>
    </div>
    <div>{{ objects.about_body|markdown }}</div>
  </div>
  <div style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>
  </article>
  <div style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

when I run this in the page source of About.html I get

```
<img src="" class="pbtthumbimg"/>
```

and I get nothing in objects.about_body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt get to it sooner. But I found a solution. It was to use django's [Flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/flatpages/). It was a no brainer. Just follow the instructions and you can add as many static pages as needed.